# How can I see the escape sequence of a given key combo (specifically Alt+letter) when I use the meta8 option in URxvt?

Tags: unicode, escaping, terminal-emulator, alt-key, urxvt

My `~/.Xdefaults` does ***not*** contain this like

```
URxvt*meta8: true
```

and if I open Vim and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, I get this

```
^[j
```

where `^[` occupies two characters but is in reality a single entity representing the escape character.

If I do put that line in my `~/.Xdefaults`, then if I hit <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Alt+j</kbd>, nothing happens; if afterwards I hit

- <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (yeah, twice) I get [`ê` (hex code `00ea`)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00EA);
- if I hit <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, I get the same;
- even <kbd>Alt+j</kbd><kbd>Alt+j</kbd> gives the same.

But it's not always like that. If after <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Alt+j</kbd> I

- hit <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>   I get `êA`
- hit <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd> I get `êB`
- hit <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>I get `êC`
- hit <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> I get `êD`

and I think the reason is that all of <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+j</kbd> are... 1-or-2-bytes sequences, whereas all of <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd>, <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd>, <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd>, <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> are longer? What I mean is that I press <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> before each of them ***when I don't have the `meta8` option enabled***, I get

- <kbd>Space</kbd>
- <kbd>y</kbd> `y`
- <kbd>z</kbd> `z`
- <kbd>Alt+j</kbd> `j`
- <kbd>ArrowUp</kbd> `OA`
- <kbd>ArrowDown</kbd> `OB`
- <kbd>ArrowRight</kbd> `OC`
- <kbd>ArrowLeft</kbd> `OD`

so it's a bit like <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> is waiting for just 1 or 2 bytes when `meta8` is disabled, and is waiting for more when it is enabled?

Comment: `showkey -a` shows you the escape sequences that your keypresses generate.